# Defining Document Root in Apache2/Cake PhP

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a broken Cake PHP site that I did not write, but am charged with fixing. I have the main controller up, however no css/js/images, and when I click a link I get a 404 not found. I believe something is incorrect with mod_rewrite or the docroot config in apache.

While reading through Cake documentation, I came across this:

"app/webroot
In a production setup, this folder should serve as the document root for your application. Folders here also serve as holding places for CSS stylesheets, images, and JavaScript files."

In my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/this-site, I see this:

```
DocumentRoot /u02/data/docroots/this_site
    <Directory /u02/data/docroots/this_site>
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride none
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

So, my question:
does the above config block need to have:
/u02/data/docroots/this_site/app/webroot as the DocumentRoot and ?

Anywhere else you can think to look for troubleshooting this?

Comment: First of all, is `mod_rewrite` enabled on apache?. Also, try changing `AllowOverride` to `all`

Comment: you defenitely need to `AllowOverride none` change to `AllowOverride All` as @Eagle mentioned. only in this case .htaccess, which used by cakephp, will work

Comment: mod_rewrite is indeed enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have access to edit the apache config files - it's most appropriate to make a standard production install.

### Fixing the docroot

> does the above config block need to have: .../app/webroot as the DocumentRoot

Assuming that path exists: yes.

This will fix the broken css/js/images.

### Fixing mod rewrite

Put the rewrite rules in the virtual host config:

```
DocumentRoot /u02/data/docroots/this_site/app/webroot
<Directory /u02/data/docroots/this_site/app/webroot>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride none
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        // added
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

This will then route requests for anything that's not a file to the application.

Verify that the rewrite rule used is compatible with the version of CakePHP in use, the above is based on the rule for [the latest release](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.3/app/webroot/.htaccess) - [it changed over the years](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commits/master/app/webroot/.htaccess) and using the wrong rewrite rule may have unexpected side effects.

### What's actually broken

```
AllowOverride none
```

This prevents the `.htaccess` files from being read by apache. If you were to change this to `AllowOverride all`, and assuming the currently-ignored `.htaccess` files exist, the site would work - but as a development install.

Comment: These answers have been very helpful. A follow up question: CakePHP uses three htaccess files. They are currently hidden, '.htaccess'. Do they need to not be hidden in order for cake to make use of them?

Comment: My previous comment was a lack of understanding on my part, and is now irrelevant. However, my last question - is it a dev install because the docroot is defined as /docroots/this_site rather than /docroots/this_site/app/webroot?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin xxxxxx@test.ro
ServerName test.ro
ServerAlias www.test.ro
DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /u02/data/docroots/this_site
ErrorLog /u02/data/docroots/this_site/error.log
CustomLog /u02/data/docroots/this_site/access.log combined

<Directory "/u02/data/docroots/this_site">
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And you should have 3 .htaccess files:

**/u02/data/docroots/this_site/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**/u02/data/docroots/this_site/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/u02/data/docroots/this_site/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps ;)